# How do non-verbal spells work in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why were there so many spells cast in the movies without saying the words to the spell?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/why-were-there-so-many-spells-cast-in-the-movies-without-saying-the-words-to-the)

Every once in a while, usually in a serious duel, you'll see a witch or wizard perform a spell without saying anything. If I remember correctly, it's usually Dumbledore and Voldemort, but I'm pretty sure I've seen Harry do it, and I think I remember Mrs. Weasley performing a non-verbal spell in Deathly Hallows 2 which totally obliterated Bellatrix Lestrange. How do these non-verbal spells work? Are there certain spells that can and can't be performed non-verbally, or does it depend on the wizard?

According to [Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Nonverbal_spell),

> Performing spells nonverbally is very difficult and requires a good
>   deal of practice, as it requires concentration and mental discipline
>   alone.

That's pretty much all it says though. Is it really as simple as "you have to concentrate really hard", or is there anything more specific you have to do?

Comment: No, that's pretty much it.

Comment: They were required to learn nonverbal spells in the sixth book.  Might not have made it to the movie, I don't think I've seen that one yet.