# Harry Potter spell languages?

Tags: harry-potter, languages, spells

In HP, do Wizards from different nationalities have different names for spells, and if so do they have to pronounce them as such during the casting?

It seems that more veteran wizards don't seem to need to pronounce many of the spells they are casting, and whilst I am sure this has been explained somewhere, I imagine it has something to do with loading the spell with meaning/empowerment.

*However*, younger wizards **DO** seem to need to say the words of the spell they are casting, and if so how is this affected by different languages? Would a mute non-muggle be unable to qualify for wizardry, for example?

Comment: Non-verbal spells [have been covered in this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/why-were-there-so-many-spells-cast-in-the-movies-without-saying-the-words-to-the)

Comment: I guessed as much with the silent spell casting, but does anyone know about the language factor?

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the language mattering much since it is as much about the spell caster's intent as it is about the language used. So in different countries they might use different words to express the same magical event. UNLESS, the Language of Magic is this pseudo-Latin used in the movies and magic won't respond to anything else. (Doesn't seem likely, but I just wanted to point that out.)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, Ta Chuck!

Comment: I don't understand why this was marked as a suplicate. The link that @Izkata posted refers to mute spells, and NOT if different languages would imply different verbal casting methods

Comment: @Oak It wasn't marked as a duplicate of the one I posted.

Comment: Fair enough, but still quite rude to mark it as a duplicate without posting the one that it's a duplicate from